# JavaScript Change Images Path That Have The Same Id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

I want to make a JavaSript code that changes the images. I mean there are two images and a button. The images path are `/assets/images/svg/outline-img1.svg` and `/assets/images/svg/outline-img.svg`. Also there is a button, that should change all the images path that have the same id (`id="changeimg"`).
I want to make that when you click onto the button, it should change the images, that contains the `changeid`. It's pretty simple but what I really want is to only change a part of the path. I mean I want to change the path from `/assets/images/svg/outline-img1.svg` to `/assets/images/svg/filled-img.svg`. But is it possible to change all the images' path that contain the `changeimg` id?
Is there any code snippet for example this?

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener("click", 
function () {
  $('#changeimg').attr('src', '/assets/images/svg/filled-'+imgname+'.svg');
/*
imgname should be the name of the image between the '/assets/images/svg/outline' and the '-.svg'. (In this example imgname = shape and imgname = shape2)
So the it should change the elements that contains the '#changeimg' id from '/assets/images/svg/outline-shape.svg' to '/assets/images/svg/filled-shape.svg'
And all the images with the changeimg id should be changed.
*/
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="/assets/images/svg/outline-shape.svg" id="changeimg">
<img src="/assets/images/svg/outline-shape2.svg" id="changeimg">

<button class="btn">Change</button>
```

I know it's a bit hard to understand, if you want I can redefine my problem.

Comment: IDs should be unique.

Comment: Then should I made it with classes?

Comment: Yes, it is hard to understand, why people use the same id multiple times, though the [docs says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) that the ids must be unique within the document.

Comment: please elaborate more .

Comment: @Swati So I want to make a button that changes all the images that have the same class, but not for one specific image. The images' path should change from `/assets/images/svg/outline-img.svg` from `/assets/images/svg/filled-img.svg` but only change the `outline` and `filled` word. Is it clear now?

Comment: yes so below solution provided doesn't work ? Also , same class here means 2 elements where classes matches ?

Comment: They don't work for me and yes same class means 2 elements with matching classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, IDs should be unique. You might even get warnings if not doing so.
Use classes, and then

```
const elements = document.getElementByClassName('changeimg')
for (let i=0; i< elements.length; i ++) {
   const imgPath = elements[i].src;
   imgPath.replace('outlined', 'filled');
   elements[i].src = imgPath; 
}
```

Comment: It's almost what I want, because it changes the paths but only change `/assets/images/svg/outline-shape.svg` to `http://localhost/assets/images/svg/outline-shape.svg`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 const x = document.querySelectorAll("#changeimg");
   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].src = "/assets/images/svg/filled-img.svg";
   }
```

Comment: This code changes all images to the same. I want to change the `outline-` to `filled-` in the path. I don't want to change the whole path, just those two words.